# How to create pcap file

Tags: c#, windows, ip, pcap

I'm looking for a way to create a pcap file from C# code.

I only want to insert source MAC + source IP + des. MAC + des. IP + data and save it as a pcap file.

I could not find any C# library that would help to do it include. https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net

Do you know an easy way to do it?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not very 'easy', but there are lots of resources  and tutorial available to help you on your way. One that I have used before is here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET

Comment: I don't want to capture pcap(/listen to network), I want to create pcap file and save it to disk

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what that means, "pcap" is short for packet capture. If you want to capture packets, you will need a packet capturing solution.

Comment: I want to create pcap file , I don't want to listen to network... just create pcap file with my data
Like "fake" pcap file